# Normal Greek sigma (and not varsigma) before apostrophe

Tags: greek

Strangely enough, LaTeX automatically changes a normal sigma (σ) into a "varsigma" (ς) if no proper letter follows. Of course, in most cases that's perfectly fine. It's a bit annoying, though, when there's an apostrophe after the sigma because the sigma isn't supposed to change in this particular case.

For example: LaTeX changes my "ἀπολλυσ᾽ οὐχ" into "ἀπολλυς᾽ οὐχ" which I don't like. Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{φίλος μ᾽ἀπόλλυc᾽οὐχ ἑκοῦσαν οὐχ᾽ ἑκών.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using the final sigma instead of the medial σ?

Comment: I think the correct term is "final sigma" instead of "varsigma".

Comment: Your input `ἀπόλλυc` has a Latin "c" at the end, which corresponds to a final sigma in the translitteration; if you simply use `ἀπόλλυσ` the output will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
@egreg : I usually use the final sigma at the end, the medial sigma in the middle; a for your last suggestion, I don't think that this solves the problem. You're right, my code contains a "c" which I stupidly left there by mistake ... I intended to write a "σ"; but even `\textgreek{φίλος μ᾽ἀπόλλυσ᾽οὐχ ἑκοῦσαν οὐχ᾽ ἑκών.}` does not produce the output I want.

Comment: I think egreg is right. The problem should not really be a problem, because both sigmas are two distinct unicode characters. In other words: what ever you type, you should get as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copying and pasting the code (after substituting `c` with `σ`) gives me what I think is the desired result:

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{φίλος μ᾽ἀπόλλυσ᾽οὐχ ἑκοῦσαν οὐχ᾽ ἑκών.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get the following if I change the output encoding to `utf8x` and remove `LGRx`:

[image]

I'm not sure whether using `΄` (U+1FBD) for the apostrophe is correct, but probably you know better.

You get the same result with `LGRx` and `utf8` if you add the following:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1FBD}{\TextGreek{\Psili{}}}
```